# Parse Html File Name From Full Path Using Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

In the following sample, I need to parse the HTML file name from the full path in a Sql Server SELECT statement:

```
Declare @x table(Id int primary key, form_url varchar(256))

Insert  @x values (1, 'Agents/Accounting/Agent.html')
Insert  @x values (2, 
'Modules/Vendors/Vendors/VendorInformation/Vendor.html')
Insert  @x values (3, 
'Modules/Customers/Customers/AccountInformation/Account.html?AccountNo')

Select * from @x
```

Note: There is a variable number of levels among paths, and there may be data following the HTML file name.

The output I'm looking for is:

- Agent.html
- Vendor.html
- Account.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL is not designed for string manipulation. But it is possible to achieve what you need:

```
Select x.*, IIF(CHARINDEX('?', sub.s) > 0,
                LEFT(sub.s, CHARINDEX('?', sub.s)-1),
                sub.s) result
from @x x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX('/',form_url) > 0,
                       RIGHT(form_url,CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(form_url))-1),
                        form_url)) sub(s);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ddd8ac71489fdc7be0b432007c6491aa)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reverse` and `charindex` to get everything up to the last slash, and then `charindex` or `substring` to limit only the HTML page.

```
Declare @x table(Id int primary key, form_url varchar(256))

Insert  @x values (1, 'Agents/Accounting/Agent.html')
Insert  @x values (2, 
'Modules/Vendors/Vendors/VendorInformation/Vendor.html')
Insert  @x values (3, 
'Modules/Customers/Customers/AccountInformation/Account.html?AccountNo')

Select 
    *
    ,FullPath = right(form_url,charindex('/',reverse(form_url)) - 1) 
    ,OnlyHtml = left(right(form_url,charindex('/',reverse(form_url)) - 1) ,charindex('.html',right(form_url,charindex('/',reverse(form_url)) + 3)))
    ,AnotherOnlyHtml = right(substring(form_url,1,charindex('.html',form_url) + 4),charindex('/',reverse(substring(form_url,1,charindex('.html',form_url) + 4))) - 1) 
from @x
```

Answer (score 0):

If interested in a helper function.  This is a modified parse/split function which accepts two non-like delimeters.  In your case as `"/"` and a `"?"`.  You may have noticed a appended a "?" just in case you were missing one.

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From @x
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](form_url+'?','/','?') B
```

**Reuturns**

[image]

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```